# Primitive of a certain class of functions

Tags: integration

Mathematica tells me that
$$
\int d x \text{ } x²\sqrt{\alpha x² + \beta x⁴}=\sqrt{x^2 (\alpha + x^2 \beta)}\bigg(\frac{-2\alpha² + x²\alpha\beta + 3x⁴\beta²}{15x \beta²}\bigg),
$$
such that it seems this integral can be done analytically. I tried for a while to figure out how to show this, but I was unsuccessful. Does anybody have an idea how to work out this type of integrals?

Comment: Take a derivative of both sides and see if the equality is indeed correct.  In the process, you might intuit a way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$I = \int {x^2 \sqrt {\alpha x^2  + \beta x^4 } dx}$$, then 
$$I  = \int {x^2 \sqrt {\alpha x^2 \left( {1 + \frac{\beta }{\alpha }x^2 } \right)} dx}  = \sqrt \alpha  \int {x^3 \sqrt {1 + \left( {\sqrt {\frac{\beta }{\alpha }} x} \right)^2 } dx} .
$$
settign $\sqrt {\frac{\beta }{\alpha }} x = \tan \theta  \Rightarrow dx = \sqrt {\frac{\alpha }{\beta }} \sec ^2 \theta d\theta $, thus $$
I = \sqrt {\frac{\alpha }{\beta }} \sqrt {\frac{{\alpha ^3 }}{{\beta ^3 }}} \sqrt \alpha  \int {\tan ^3 \theta \sqrt {1 + \tan ^2 \theta } \sec ^2 \theta d\theta } 
 = \frac{{\alpha ^{5/2} }}{{\beta ^2 }}\int {\tan ^3 \theta \sec ^3 \theta d\theta } 
$$ Letting $u=\sec \theta$ $\Rightarrow$ $du = \sec \theta \tan \theta d\theta$

\begin{align}
I= \frac{{\alpha ^{5/2} }}{{\beta ^2 }}\int {\tan ^3 \theta \sec ^3 \theta d\theta } &= \frac{{\alpha ^{5/2} }}{{\beta ^2 }}\int {\tan \theta \sec \theta \tan ^2 \theta \sec ^2 \theta d\theta }
\\ 
&= \frac{{\alpha ^{5/2} }}{{\beta ^2 }}\int {\tan \theta \sec \theta (u^2-1)u^2  \frac{du}{\sec\theta \tan \theta}}
\\
&= \frac{{\alpha ^{5/2} }}{{\beta ^2 }}\int {(u^2-1)u^2  du} 
\\
&= \frac{{\alpha ^{5/2} }}{{\beta ^2 }} (\frac{u^5}{5}-\frac{u^3}{3})+C
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Factor $x^2$ inside the radical sign, then extract it from under it, and let $t=x^2$, then $u=\sqrt{a+bt}$.